# Facing problems while moving workbooks between solution environment (Development, Production etc. ) in Tableau Server?

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on **Tableau Server**  where I have say, three solution environments viz. `Development` `Staging` and `Production`.
I have created workbooks in `Development` environment and each workbook use many data sources.

> For instance lets say I created the workbook `Account Workbook` and I have used these two data sources `Dev-DataSource1` and `Dev-DataSource2`. I have other data sources available like `Stage-DataSource1`, `Stage-DataSource2`, `Dev-DataSource3`, `Stage-DataSource3` etc.

The problem I am facing is while moving workbooks from `Development` to `Staging` environment, the data sources remains the same.

> So continuing with the same instance if I move `Account Workbook` to `Staging` from `Development` environment, `Account Workbook` still uses the same data sources `Dev-DataSource1` and `Dev-DataSource2`. I want it to use the `Stage-DataSource1` and `Stage-DataSource2` .

This might be a very trivial question or maybe a bad design, but I have created so many workbooks such that creating them again might take loads of time, so please refrain from asking me to recreate those workbooks again. If there is no other way other than that then do tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your different environments sites or projects? Or completely separate  servers? It’s a lot easier to move and share content between projects than between servers.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore The solution I have is associated with tableau server site and the site contains a separate project for solution environment (Development, Staging, and Production).  So basically they are projects.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just edit the data sources, for instance from Dev-DataSource1 to Stage-DataSource1?
I assume they have the exact same structures, field names, etc?
Right click on the data source and click "Edit". When in the data source page, pull in table(s) from 
the new datasource and replace the one(s) that are there. If you have joins you may need to recreate them. If you have custom sql you just need to change your sql to point to the new table(s).

You will need to refresh your data sources. It should recognize the fields assuming they are exactly the same as before.
If you need to edit the connection, you can do that as well (if you need to point to a different server, etc.)
Make sure you have a backup of your workbook in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Your assumption about the structures of data source is correct. I created many calculated fields in it. If I replace/change the data source then all the calculated field will be gone. Seems like the calculated fields are connected to a particular data source only. So I reckon editing the data source would not work.

Comment: @Prakhar, if you just use the same data sources that are there now, but change the tables that the data source is pointing to inside of the data source (don't replace data sources or make a new ones) and if, as you say, the structures of the new tables are exactly the same as before, then the calculated fields should be okay.

Comment: Yeah this might work. I have to check if it is possible in our servers.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be worth your time to look into the Tableau Python document API: https://github.com/tableau/document-api-python

This would allow you to do (some/all?) of what are describing programmatically.

Comment: I cant apply this info in my project. I am working on a cloud and it has some server restriction. But this is a good reference to keep in mind.